# parse XML in a string column in an existing DataFrame and add it as a new column with parsed results in scala

Tags: xml-parsing, xmlreader

I have a requirement where I need to process a column in a dataframe containing an XML and also want to keep original columns as it is. Parsed elemnts should be added as new columns in existing dataframe.
MyDataframe look like this -

```
`    +---------+--------------------+
     |id|            xmldata|
    +---------+--------------------+
    |    18284|<?xml version="1....|
    |    18307|<?xml version="1....|
    |    18297|<?xml version="1....|
    |    18282|<?xml version="1....|
     +---------+--------------------+`
```

I want to expand it with parsed elements from xmldata column
``
+---------+--------------------++---------+--------+------+------+------+
|id|            xmldata          |cust_test|cust_val|Addrl1|Addrl2|Addrl3|
+---------+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------++------+---+
|    18284|<?xml version="1....|        a|     100|   123|   277|   311|
|    18284|<?xml version="1... |        b|     200|   176|  null|   344|
|    18284|<?xml version="1....|        c|     300|  null|   299|   366|
+---------+--------------------++---------+--------+------+------+------+

``
I need dataframe with existing columns and parsed columns